Find $T$-invariant subspaces of $A$.
Let $V=\Bbb R^4$ and the matrix respect to canonic basis,
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 &1 & 1\\0 & 2&2 &0\\ 0 & 0 &2 & 0\\ -1 & 1 &0 & 3\end{bmatrix}  $$
I saw in other answer that if we know which is the Jordan matrix associated to $A$ then we know how find the $T$-invariant subspaces. I found that the characteristic polynomial is $C_T(t)=(t-2)^4$ and minimal is $M_T=(t-2)^3$. And the Jordan bases and matrix are $\beta=\{(2,1,1,1),(1,2,0,0),(1,0,0,1),(2,1,0,1)\}$,
$$J_A=\begin{bmatrix}2& 0&0 & 0\\1& 2&0 &0\\ 0 & 1&2 & 0\\ 0 & 0&0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
Then can u explain me, how with that i can find the $T$-invariant subespaces. Thank y'all.

Finding $f-$invariant subspaces. This is the answer that I saw and $A$ is matrix associated to $T$ with respect to canonic basis.

Think about how you apply linear transformations using matrix multiplication.

@AnneBauval I forgot put, $A$ is matrix associated to $T$ respect canonic basis. Don't say what is $T$ explicit

Have you learned about generalized eigenspaces? Notice how we can split $J_A$ into 2 blocks (such that everything outside of those blocks is 0), as follows: the first block is the 3x3 in the top left, and the second block is the bottom right entry ("2"). So in that fourth coordinate, $J_A$ takes in something in that subspace (span of that fourth basis vector) and returns something in that same subspace. A similar result holds for the first three basis vectors in input (i.e. columns) staying within the first three rows in output. That at least tells you that span is T-invariant. But definitely I recommend reading about generalized eigenspaces to see that they're invariant.

Let $V_1:=\operatorname{span}(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ and $V_2:=\operatorname{span}(\beta_4)$. As explained in the answer to your linked post,

the $T$-invariant subspaces of $V_1$ are $$W_1=\{0\},\operatorname{span}(\beta_3),\operatorname{span}(\beta_2,\beta_3),V_1,$$
those of $V_2$ are
$$W_2=\{0\},V_2,$$
and those of $V$ are all the $W_1\oplus W_2$.

